# Ubuntu 16.04 second monitor is black

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors

I use ubuntu 16.04 and I connected my second monitor, it is detected but it is black.
Output of `xrandr -q` :

```
DP-1 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm 1280x1024 60.02*+ 75.02
1152x864 75.00
1024x768 75.03 60.00
832x624 74.55
800x600 75.00 60.32
640x480 75.00 59.94
720x400 70.08
```

It is connected with VGA. What can I do to turn on second monitor?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is with refresh rate.

You can change it in Display Settings (maybe 60 would be alright)

Or you can use this command  `xrandr` to see what's your second screen name and what resolutions/refresh rates does it support. For example XX.
Then you can set it by:

`xrandr --output DP-1 --rate XX`

Comment: 30Hz is pretty painful to use - why not 60Hz? (the default for most LCD/LED panels)

Comment: @Nmath Yes, makes sence. I said 30 at first, since it have tried this before (and the frequency that my Video Projector suppurtes was 30 Hz)